# How to combine in a sentence two verb–preposition pairs that have the same object?

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, prepositions, parallelism

Examples:

> 1. Data can be imported to and exported from the application.
> 2. Data can be imported and exported from the application.
> 3. Data can be imported to the application and exported from it.
>
> ---
>
> 1. The manager defined the products that should be added to and removed from the store.
> 2. The manager defined the products that should be added and removed from the store.
> 3. The manager defined the products that should be added to the store and removed from it.

I assume that the third sentence is correct in my examples. My question is whether the two other sentences are correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Examples #1 is correct in both sections, and are examples of basic parallelism. However, example #2 is wrong is both sections.

The basic test is if you can deconstruct your parallelism into two grammatical sentences *without adding new words*:

**Example #1 works**

> Data can be imported to and exported from the application.

deconstructs to

> Data can be imported to the application. Data can be exported from the application.

**Example #2 is awkward**

> Data can be imported and exported from the application.

deconstructs to

> Data can be imported from the application.
>   Data can be exported from the application.

Note the "import from" wordage above. This is awkward because the idiom here is "**import to** the application" or "**export from** the application". Even worse is the idea of adding something "from" a store.

Answer (score 3):

In both examples, (1) is also an accepted structure, although it is usually written with commas or dashes:

> Data can be imported to, and exported from, the application.

Comment: I would only use commas or dashes if the second verb–preposition pair is to be read as a parenthetical remark or an afterthought. I see no reason to add punctuation otherwise.