# Does one include a comma after the last proposition in a list of multiple preposition-verb pairs

Tags: verbs, prepositions, objects

Should I do this:

> The developers are less experienced in, or passionate about, UX.

Or should I remove the last comma:

> The developers are less experienced in, or passionate about UX.

[This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73242/preposition-use-multiple-prepositions-to-the-same-noun?lq=1) seems to imply that the latter form is best but I feel that the former reads better. Is this feeling mistaken?

Comment: I would use the commas. I would also add the word *less* in front of the word *passionate*: *The developers are less experienced in, or less passionate about, UX.*

Comment: It does need some delimitation, but commas sound wrong. I'd use a dash: _The developers are less experienced in – or passionate about – UX._ Better still, repeat _less_ before passionate to balance the comparative: _The developers are less experienced in – or less passionate about – UX._ It still sounds ugly with such a short word at the end, but it's parallel and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely not the second one. Every authority I have to consult says both commas, or neither. I think it's fine in modern writing to leave them out.

But I question the "or" in the sentence. It's not describing an either-or proposition. It's a compound problem (they're bad in two ways), requiring "and."

The developers, unlike the technical writers, are less experienced in and less passionate about user interface design.

Avoid "UX" as jargon. Yes, I'm a technical writer.