# Is it grammatically correct to have multiple clauses and prepositions?

Tags: prepositions, commas, clauses

Is the following sentence grammatically correct and if so, are the commas necessary?

> Exclude anyone who's inactive at, or opposed to, the event.

If not, is it grammatically correct to instead use parentheses?

> Exclude anyone who's inactive at (or opposed to) the event.

Comment: You can find the answer here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73242/preposition-use-multiple-prepositions-to-the-same-noun

Comment: Can you clarify what 'inactive from the event' might mean? [Adjective + prepositional phrase] strings ('sad about his loss'; 'opposed to capital punishment) are common.  It's fine to 'pair up' similar constructions with related meanings, and deleting one noun phrase ('Harry is prepared for though a little apprehensive about his exams'; 'y is greater than or equal to x'. But silly examples must be avoided ('Tommy was good at but injured from playing football').

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've updated the example sentences. One who's inactive at the event is one who's not engaged in an activity. E.g. Not dutifully volunteering at a charity event.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is it grammatically incorrect to apply commas to your example ('Harry is prepared for, though a little apprehensive about, his exams')?

Comment: On ELU, and in most scholarly treatments of grammar, punctuation and grammar are distinct. // Probably, most traditional textbooks would prefer the offsetting commas, but there is a move towards lighter punctuation. I don't consider them necessary here as I'd hardly pause in reading (intonation would demarcate just fine, and I think the reading sounds precious with short pauses) and clarification isn't necessary. If I wanted 'pregnant pauses' for emphasis, I'd use dashes.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I appreciate this context. If it's appropriate for you to submit your comments as an answer, I will select your answer as the correct answer and close off this question. Thanks.