# Verbs + (different) prepositions in or proposition

Tags: prepositions

How do I handle prepositional verbs in an or proposition? Here is an example:

```
if a user needs to be added or removed ? the database
```

The question mark is there as a placeholder. Since you add *to* and you remove *from*, writing `if a user needs to be added or removed from the database` seems a bit awkward, so does `if a user needs to be added to or removed from the database`. I'm interested both in what is right in formal English and in a less formal setting - could `if a user needs to be added to/removed from the database` work? Thanks!

Comment: Also see [How to combine in a sentence two verb–preposition pairs that have the same object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/how-to-combine-in-a-sentence-two-verb-preposition-pairs-that-have-the-same-objec)

Comment: Also see [How to handle verbs that use different preposition when used in pairs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/407914/how-to-handle-verbs-that-use-different-preposition-when-used-in-pairs)

Comment: @Clare I was sure there would be an answer somewhere but did not manage to find the right search terms. Thanks a lot, have a nice day