# Combine two sentences properly

Tags: grammar, expressions

I want to combine the following two sentences properly:

1. It requires writing information to an external memory.
2. It requires retrieving information from an external memory.

If I omit "information" in the above sentences, I would combine them into

**It requires writing to and retrieving from an external memory.**

But things becomes complicated when the word "information" is involved, and I don't know how to express it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to combine in a sentence two verb–preposition pairs that have the same object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/how-to-combine-in-a-sentence-two-verb-preposition-pairs-that-have-the-same-objec)

Comment: Hi @BenjaminKuykendall, My question is different. I stressed if "information" were omitted, I knew the right combination. But I don't know how to combine them if it presents.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. The answer isn't that different, but I'm happy to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the pronoun *it* then you can avoid repeating the word *information*.

> It requires writing information to and retrieving it from an external memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest method is to write it like this:

> It requires writing and retrieving information to and from an external memory.