# Different adjectives following a list in a sentence

Tags: articles

Example:

I hope to help with the vision of and research at Booze Drinkers Ltd.

The question is that vision is followed with a different article than 'research'. In separate sentences it's vision of booze drinkers, and research at booze drinkers right? Or if this isn't the best example, I am thinking of situations where what I'm asking about does apply.

I don't know if you say

- I hope to help with the _____, ____, ____ and, ___ at Your Mom Gay Enterprises.

Or

- I hope to help with the ____ at, _____ of, ____ in, and _____ with Your Mom Gay Ltd.

Comment: Which words function as adjectives in your example?

Comment: You seem confused about grammatical terms. "of" and "at" are prepositions and you don't have any adjectives in your sentences.

Comment: This question is about verb-preposition pairs rather than noun-preposition pairs, but the same principle applies: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/how-to-combine-in-a-sentence-two-verb-preposition-pairs-that-have-the-same-objec