# Is “I’m obsessed and loyal to that one boy who isn’t mine and doesn’t even know me” correct?

Tags: grammar

If that sentence is not correct about grammar, please fix it for me

Comment: It's grammatically fine, but requests for proofreading are off-topic.

Comment: I won't fix it for you, but will point out what is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine in a sentence two verb–preposition pairs that have the same object?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1035/how-to-combine-in-a-sentence-two-verb-preposition-pairs-that-have-the-same-objec)

Answer (score 1):

**obsessed** is complemented by a phrase introduced by **with**.

**loyal** is complemented by a phrase introduced by **to**.

So you cannot combine them as you have done, and then complement the two with a prepositional phrase that is suitable only for one of them.

Comment: Elision, happens all the time. Any references to back up the answer to an off-topic question?

Comment: What is off-topic is the request to fix, which I didn't do.   It's not elision, but a failure to complement the adjective properly. People say stuff like that, true, but the question doesn't always come down to what is fundamentally grammatical, but to what is expedient in real world contexts. That's the aspect of usage that interests me, how to engineer the utterance so it works better.to

Comment: You proofread it, didn't like it  and explained to the OP why it didn't work.

Comment: You are using the verb **proofread** very loosely.  I did nothing of the kind. I discussed two adjectives and their differing complements.  I read it.